# Could not create the view: com/ibm/domino/xsp/module/nsf/platform/NotesPlatform

Tags: java, lotus-notes, xpages, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to open an xpage in the notes client on a Mac but I get an error. I have tried many different xpages but non of them work in the notes client and I get the same error for all.

Notes Version Release 8.5.3FP2 SHF143[image]
OSX 10.8.2

any ideas?

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/domino/xsp/module/nsf/platform/NotesPlatform
    at com.ibm.xsp.rcp.XspViewPart.init(XspViewPart.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewPane.setVisible(ViewPane.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
    at com.ibm.rcp.ui.internal.presentations.StandAloneStackPresentation.selectPart(StandAloneStackPresentation.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1209)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1608)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.createControl(PartStack.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.createControl(PartStack.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartSashContainer.createControl(PartSashContainer.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveHelper.activate(PerspectiveHelper.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.onActivate(Perspective.java:968)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:3568)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busySetPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$16(WorkbenchPage.java:1016)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$18.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3667)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:3665)
    at com.ibm.rcp.platform.personality.internal.window.DynamicPerspective.open(DynamicPerspective.java:90)
    at com.ibm.rcp.platform.personality.internal.window.SwitcherWindowHelper.show(SwitcherWindowHelper.java:238)
    at com.ibm.rcp.platform.personality.widgets.TabbedPerspectiveSwitcher.show(TabbedPerspectiveSwitcher.java:1310)
    at com.ibm.xsp.rcp.xphandler.OpenXPHandler.createXPagesView(OpenXPHandler.java:254)
    at com.ibm.xsp.rcp.xphandler.OpenXPHandler.run(OpenXPHandler.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UILockListener.doPendingWork(UILockListener.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer$3.run(UISynchronizer.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3515)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3243)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2384)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2348)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2200)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.ibm.rcp.personality.framework.internal.RCPApplication.run(RCPApplication.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1239)
    at com.ibm.rcp.core.internal.launcher.Main.startLaunch(Main.java:880)
    at com.ibm.rcp.core.internal.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1290)
    at com.ibm.rcp.core.internal.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1210)

Comment: Looks like you should open a ticket with IBM...

Comment: I'd rather live with it!

Comment: There is an SPR LHEY8CZJSM which exactly matches your issue, but was fixed before 8.5.3 shipped. I suspect your issue has to do with the fact you are using Mountain Lion. So I would also recommend to open a PMR. ps. Support people have feelings too. :'(

Comment: Simon, If it was a customer case I would have reported it

Comment: You could try starting the client with the "RPARAMS -console" option. It might show other errors before you get to that.

Comment: Any idea how to do that on a mac?